# How to re-shape a bent steel fender

Tags: repair, steel, fenders

I've got an old road bike with polished steel fenders, the rear one of which unfortunately got bent during transport:

[image: Rear view of fender with metal "crease" in the middle]

As you can see in the lower half of the photo, the two sides of the fender were bent towards each other, causing a "crease" to appear in the middle of the fender.

[image: Left side of fender with dent at lower end]

On the left side of the fender, as pictured above, I had tried to use some pliers to pry the side "away" from the other one in an attempt to fix the "crease" in the metal. Unfortunately, this just made a plier-shaped dent at the end of the fender.

[image: Right side of fender with dent]

Lastly, on the right side of the fender, as pictured above, there is a somewhat shallower and "wider" dent which also appeared after transporting the bike.

How can I re-shape the fender so that it is not "creased" and not dented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally you'd take the fender off a bike, put it on an anvil, find the right place on the horn of the anvil that matches the radius of the curve, and bang out the ding. Then you'd buff out any scratches or rechrome it.

[image: anvil]

(this anvil's horn is upward curving, you'd want one with a downward curve that matches your fender angle more).

You don't need a big huge anvil, there are hobby anvils that are much smaller. You do want to choose the right type of hammer (most likely bronze faced) so that you don't scratch or mar the finish too much.

You can  also take it to an autobody shop or a metalworker and have them do it for you.

Comment: Someone skilled with a plenishing wheel or an english hammer can fix this kind of thing.  Try an automotive body shop that specialises in vintage cars.   If it doesn't interfere with the function, consider just leaving it as-is.  You might want to spray on something like zinc spray paint to prevent rust.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as The Answer but unfortunately I won't be able to deal with this for quite some time given that it's a lot more involved than I had hoped it would be...